# How to scroll the page in selenium webdriver to specific link

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Iam not able to scroll to the value specified. in below link

```
http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/samsung~brand/pr?sid=tyy,4io&otracker=hp_nmenu_sub_electronics_0_Samsung
```

i need to click  **Exclude Out of Stock**  for that i need to scroll the webpage and click it.

through automation iam not able to achieve this

iam using the below code to get coordinates

```
    Point hoverItem =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@title='Exclude Out of Stock']/a")).getLocation();
    System.out.println("dsds"+hoverItem);
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return window.title;");    
    Thread.sleep(6000);
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+(hoverItem.getY())+");");
```

and to scroll down iam using the below code.

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(143,1459)", "");
```

then iam clicking this using link.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@title='Exclude Out of Stock']/a")).click();
```

above code is not working.

if i run the code and scroll manually then it is clicking the specified value,

how to overcome the situation.
 Code

```
   package Examples;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

//import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Point;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Flipkart {
    public static WebDriver driver;


    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass()
    {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


    }

    @Test

    public void FlipkartTest() throws InterruptedException
    {

        driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();


        navback();
        System.out.println("22  "+driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a")).getText());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[2]/a")).click();


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@title='Exclude Out of Stock']/a")).click();

    }

    public void navback()
    {
          WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li/a/span"));
          Actions action = new Actions(driver);
          action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
    }



    @AfterClass
    public void tear()
    {
       // driver.quit();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver automatically scrolls to locate the element, so just `findElement()` with `click()` should work, provided that the selector used to locate the element is correct.

The element takes some time to appear, so i would wait for it using [implicit or explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#availability input.facetoption"))).click();
```

Comment: iam not able to select it, tried the wait for it's not selecting. new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#availability input.facetoption"))).click(); (or) or using this driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@title='Exclude Out of Stock']/a")).click();

Comment: It worked for me...what error are you getting?can you paste it as part of your question?

Comment: as Amith asked added the code, when iam running the code it is not selecting the "Exclude Out of Stock" and it is returning back to original page.

Comment: I ran your code,its working fine..the checkbox `Exclude Out of Stock` is getting checked

Comment: Amith, when i run the same code at my place, it is getting redirected to www.flipkart.com Expected is the Exclude out of stock check box should be checked and changes should get applied in the webpage and should be on the same webpage . what can be a problem iam not able to understand.

Comment: Which browser version are u using?

Comment: Browser firefox of Ver. 26

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use By.lintext instead of xpath - By.linkText("Exclude Out of Stock")
2. As Amith mentions, click would automatically scroll.
3. Before trying out js, try using the Actions methods.  Movetoelement should also work.